# How to display using a For Loop from an array list of movies only if movie wasSuccesfull(true)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, boolean

```
var movies = [
        forestGump = {
            title: "Forest Gump",
            yearReleased: 1994,
            director: "Robert Zemeckis",
            genre: "Comedy",
            wasSuccessfull: true
        },
        harryPotter = {
            title: "Harry Potter",
            yearReleased: 2001,
            director: "Mike Newell",
            genre: "Fantasy Fiction",
            wasSuccessfull: true
        },
        titanic = {
            title: "Titanic",
            yearReleased: 1998,
            director: "James Cameron",
            genre: "Romance",
            wasSuccessFull: true
        },
        bestWorstMovie = {
            title: "Best Worst Movie",
            yearReleased: 2009,
            director: "Michael Stephen",
            genre: "Comedy",
            wasSuccessfull: false
        },
        troll2 = {
            title: "Troll 2",
            yearReleased: 2003,
            director: "Shawn Black",
            genre: "Horror",
            wasSuccessfull: false

        }
    ];
for (var i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
        if (movies === true);

    }
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is all code, and does not follow the guidelines found in [ask]. Please read through the tutorial so that you can understand what constitutes a well asked question; that will make it easier for the Stack Overflow Community to help you with your issue!

Comment: `var successfulMovies = movies.filter(function(m) { return m.wasSuccessful; });`

Comment: Love the bonus where global vars are also getting created.

Answer (score 0):

Using this:

```
movies.filter(function(movie){
    if(movie.wasSuccessfull) 
        return movie}
);
```

or :

```
movies.filter( movie => movie.wasSuccessfull);
```

Comment: You can improve the code by returning just `return movie.wasSuccessfull`. The filter method just keeps the elements that produce a true when fed to the callback

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(movies.filter(function(movie) {
  return movie.wasSuccessfull;
}));
```